# Why this approach to 8 Queens problem always returns 0

Tags: c++, backtracking

Here is my code.

```
using namespace std;


int ans = 0;
string il[8]; //squares which cannot contain any queens


void quen(int x, int y, bool table1[15],bool table2[15], bool table3[8]){
    if(il[y][x]!='*'){
        if(table3[x]==0){
            if(table2[x+y]==0){
                if(table1[7-y+x]==0){
                    table1[7-y+x]=1;
                    table2[x+y]=1;
                    table3[x]=1;
                    
                    if(y==7){
                        ans++;
                        return;
                    }
                    else{
                        for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
                            quen(i, y+1, table1, table2, table3);
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        string str;
        cin>>str;
        il[i]=str;
    }
    bool table1[15]={0};
    bool table2[15]={0};
    bool table3[8]={0};
    for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
        quen(i, 0, table1, table2, table3);
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

I'm trying to solve the CSES "Chessboard and Queens" problem. The vector of strings called il represents the squares which cannot contain any queens.

Example Input:

```
........
........
..*.....
........
........
.....**.
...*....
........
```

But my code always returns 0(surprisingly y is never 7) and I couldn't figure out why. Can you please help me.

Comment: This seems like a very good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. Like for example use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. Use pen and paper to keep track of variables as you make the recursive calls.

Comment: Do you think your code is simple enough for other people to read it and understand what it is supposed to do without any context?

Comment: You'll be glad to hear that you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for: it runs your program, one line at a time, and [shows you what's happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/)!! This is something that's every C++ developer must know how to do. With your debugger's help you'll able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: It's not obvious at all how that code is expected to work, but if you're planning on backtracking, the lack of backtracking might be the problem. (On a side note, if you can't think of better names than "table1", "table2", and "table3", it's usually a sign that you don't really know what they're for.)

Comment: The value of the tables never decrease ... e.g. when coming back from a previous attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking):

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
int ans = 0;
string il[8]; // squares which cannot contain any queens
 
void quen(int x, int y, bool table1[15], bool table2[15], bool table3[8]) {
  if (il[y][x] != '*' && !table3[x] && !table2[x + y] && !table1[7 - y + x]) {
    table1[7 - y + x] = true;
    table2[x + y] = true;
    table3[x] = true;
    if (y == 7) {
      ans++;
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        quen(i, y + 1, table1, table2, table3);
      }
    }
    table1[7 - y + x] = false;
    table2[x + y] = false;
    table3[x] = false;
  }
}
 
int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    il[i] = str;
  }
  bool table1[15] = {0};
  bool table2[15] = {0};
  bool table3[8] = {0};
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    quen(i, 0, table1, table2, table3);
  }
  cout << ans << endl;
}
```

***Note:** There are many best practices that can be followed to improve the readability of this code.*